# Is $(_{1}∩_{1})∩(_{2}∩_{2}) = (_1∩_2)∩(_1∩_2)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have 4 Sets,

$_{1},_{1},_{2},_{2}$.

Is $(_{1}\cap _{1})\cap(_{2}\cap_{2}) = (_1\cap_2)\cap(_1\cap_2)$ ?

If yes,Why ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why ? Can you explain this please ?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Do an element chase, suppose $x$ is in the left side. Show it is in the right side. Suppose $x$ is in the right side. Show it is in the left side.

Comment: The operations are associative and commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Set intersection $\cap$ is commutative

$A\cap B=B \cap A$

and associative

$A\cap(B \cap C)=(A \cap B) \cap C$

Use these properties and prove your statement.